# How to implement more moderate long-term consequences after numerous PCs are knocked out?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat

I ran a session a while back in which the players were fighting a griffon boss.  The griffon had KO'd 6 of the 7 pcs, when the last PC finished off the monster.  The PC helped up everyone and all was dandy.

This doesn't seem appropriate for players to be able to get up and rest without any consequence, as if nothing had happened.  This goes especially as 6 of 7 players were KO'd. The only way that the players wouldn't be able to simply "rest off" damage is if there was a TPK.

How do I apply consequences of more moderate severity which affect players in the the long term, without resorting to harsh extremes such as killing off the character(s)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78497/discussion-on-question-by-tuskiomi-how-to-implement-more-moderate-long-term-cons).

Comment: Did none of the player characters fail 3 death saves before the fight ended? Even after the fight ended, downed PCs would continue making death saves in turn order, and unless the surviving PC healed them all at once, he could only help one at a time. And unless the surviving PC actually healed them rather than simply stabilizing them, he could only stabilize one character each round - at which rate it'd take 6 rounds to stabilize the others, and they'd all need to avoid failing 3 death saves during that time. That seems highly unlikely...

Comment: @V2Blast unless some of them were stabilized during the fight

Comment: I really want to answer this with "You don't", but I will first ask some questions to make sure I'm not just making a badwrongfun statement: 1) Have you talked to your players? Do they agree there should be more consequences to what happened? 2) What kind of consequences do you want? In particular, what do you mean by long term? Permanent? For the next week? Month? Following day? 3) What is you intention behind the question? Realism? Making the players judge more/better if they should engage a combat or not? Step up the challenge? Other?

Comment: I want to second what HellSaint says.  1)What is your goal with this? And 2)How permanent (or crippling) do you want this to be? NautArch gives a good list of official ways you can make the game as a whole grittier. But my first understanding was that you are looking for a special event to highlight the difference between a fight where one character is downed and one where one character is still up.

Comment: @HellSaint 1) no.  2) all of the above 3) to make combat not an all or nothing ordeal.

Comment: @3C273 i just want a result that isn't black or white. something between win and lose.

Comment: @tuskiomi The "2) all of the above" makes the question too broad, from my point of view. The "3)" at least clarifies enough for me to provide an answer, though. So let's try it.

Comment: @tuskiomi I'll try to see if I can make up a response to this without it being too far into speculations for the taste of this site. On the short term, I suggest looking at the possibility of  applying some form of ArchNaut's otions temporarily (if you hadn't looked into it yet)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## [Injuries](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#Injuries), [Massive Damage](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#MassiveDamage), [Adventuring Options](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#AdventuringOptions), and player happiness.

[Chapter 9 of the DMG](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#Chapter9DungeonMastersWorkshop) contains some rule variants and guidelines for introducing ongoing after-battle effects and different adventuring options for a grittier game.

The following are some of the effects that will trigger a roll on these tables, but as a DM you can always tweak them.

> **Injuries**
>
> Damage normally leaves no lingering effects. This option introduces the potential for long-term injuries.
>
> It’s up to you to decide when to check for a lingering injury. A creature might sustain a lingering injury under the following circumstances:
>
> - When it takes a critical hit
> - When it drops to 0 hit points but isn’t killed outright
> - When it fails a death saving throw by 5 or more

and

> **Massive Damage**
>
> This optional rule makes it easier for a creature to be felled by massive damage.
>
> When a creature takes damage from a single source equal to or greater than half its hit point maximum, it must succeed on a DC 15 Constitution saving throw or suffer a random effect determined by a roll on the System Shock table. For example, a creature that has a hit point maximum of 30 must make that Constitution save if it takes 15 damage or more from a single source.

### Adventuring Options (also found in Chapter 9 of the DMG)

These introduce some different mechanics for non-combat and how PCs recover. You can see the sections on [Healing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#Healing), and [Rest Variants](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#RestVariants).

> **Slow Natural Healing**
>
> Characters don’t regain hit points at the end of a long rest. Instead, a character can spend Hit Dice to heal at the end of a long rest, just as with a short rest.
>
> This optional rule prolongs the amount of time that characters need to recover from their wounds without the benefits of magical healing and works well for grittier, more realistic campaigns.

and

> **Gritty Realism**
>
> This variant uses a short rest of 8 hours and a long rest of 7 days. This puts the brakes on the campaign, requiring the players to carefully judge the benefits and drawbacks of combat. Characters can’t afford to engage in too many battles in a row, and all adventuring requires careful planning.

## TALK TO YOUR PLAYERS

### Table Acceptance

These tables and effects represent a drastic change from how your table has run and you should absolutely talk with your players to see if this is the kind of game they are looking for. Are they wanting gritty? Are they wanting more dangerous/deadly? If so, then this is a may be what everyone is looking for.

Answer (score 14):

## Talk

Before starting, as you mentioned you didn't talk to your players, **TALK TO YOUR PLAYERS.** Align your expectation with theirs, don't just change the entire system on your own.

## Rethink what combat means for you (and for your setting)

Opposite to [NautArch's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/123939/43856), which explores the problem from a mechanical point of view (and which I would also give as a separate answer if he didn't do it faster than me), mine will focus on [gm-techniques](/questions/tagged/gm-techniques) for the encounter to have consequences through story and role playing rather than house ruling. I don't necessarily think it is a *better* solution, but I think it's *another* (good) solution.

I'll start with: read [this](https://magbonch.wordpress.com/2011/12/13/inconsequentialness_of_combat/). I will recreate this text from my own point of view and experience. First because RPG.se doesn't like "link-only" answers. Second because the text is about [dnd-4e](/questions/tagged/dnd-4e), so even though it's a direct translation (it's more about DM techniques than system, and the system problems the text touches are for all D&D editions I know of), I'll make it. A similar point is made by [AngryGM](http://theangrygm.com/four-things-youve-never-heard-of-that-make-encounters-not-suck/) (Disclaimer: offensive language and everything else we are used to from AngryGM), if you want a longer and angrier text.

You state in a comment that you want

> to make combat not an "all or nothing" ordeal.

**This is a problem of how you are handling encounters.** You are, currently, treating an encounter as

> Monster wants to kill party. Party wants to kill monster. One of the sides win (preferably the players, since TPKs mean game over), goal accomplished, everything's over. Next encounter. Another monster wants to kill the party [...]

or at least that's what your body text tells me.

When you treat the encounters like that, as noted in the text I linked, **combat becomes inconsequential**. That's because there are only two possible outcomes, victory or death, and death is undesirable.

Think about other interactions in the game: if there's no consequence, you don't make the player roll a dice, right? So, if there's no consequence for combat, why are you making that combat at all?

So, a few steps before I present you my solution to your problems:

- Only make the combat non-trivial if there's meaning to it.
- Give the enemies motivation and goals.
- Premise: the enemies want to live.

My solution: make goals that are accomplished without killing the party or party members. A few examples:

- Thugs want to steal from the party. After knocking out 6 members, they decide to gather what they can and run with that. Permanent (or at least until the party decides to find their hideout) consequence: loss of some items, gold and whatever else. Obviously, don't handicap the party too much with that, but that will depend on how many thugs the party left alive before getting majorly knocked out. This is a suggested approach (in place of TPK) in a combat from a published campaign I'm currently running - Lost Mine of Phandelver.
- The party is invading a castle. After most of them got knocked out, one of the two remaining guards, that were almost dead, runs and sets the alarm. His goal is to protect the castle, not to single-handedly kill the party. Mid-term consequence: the castle is now better protected. Chances of being surprised are higher, chances of surprising are almost null. Traps might have been set. This is, again, an approach that is common in LMoP.
- The party is trying to loot a dragon's lair. When it reaches low life, after having knocked most party members, he notices he can escape from that last member, which he wouldn't be able to if there were still 7 people up. It quickly grabs the most important treasures from his hoard and flies away, dodging the arrows and spells from the surviving member. Consequence: the loot was reduced. This comes from the premise: **the dragon wants to live**.

Note that, in all of these scenarios I've presented, the enemies **could** try to do the same, even if the 7 party members were up. This would be harder, and the enemies could **not try to**, thinking it was impossible to start with.

If you don't want to make the enemies run (btw, you should give the XP even if they do, to be clear), you can work with that concept. If the party's goal is to kill, while the other side has a different goal, **both can be accomplished**, and the party still "lost" since the enemies accomplished it before.

---

For the second part of this answer, I'll state: **there are already consequences, you are not exploring them.**

## Adventuring Time

After your party gets almost-TPK'd by a single encounter, they will be spending a good amount of time resting. The more frequently they are resting, the more time they are wasting. My current campaign has a rival adventuring party (remember: your PCs **are not the only adventurers in the world**, unless your setting specifically says so) which essentially serves as a time limit for the party to accomplish what they need to. If they spend too much time resting, the other party gets to the loot before them. Personally, I set this time limit with a laarge margin, it's so just they don't waste too much time.

## Spell Slots and Class Feature Uses

Spell Slots (and other class features such action surge, rage, second wind) are as much as a resource as HP is. Sure, they also come back from a rest... if the party can rest. A short-term (but not as short as you might be thinking) consequence of every combat is: **the next combat is harder.** The same concept of resource applies to **magic consumable items** and **magic item charges**, and these don't even come back with rest (ok, some magic item charges do).

## Social Consequences

Someone was on the scene, watching the fight from afar, scared. This person then details what he saw to the city. Rumours spread.

> **City Mayor**: I thought you were heroic adventurers, but you almost got rekt by that weak Griffon? Lancelot here kills one of those daily.

All that "we are amazing" talk from the party's Bard is now seen as arrogance and lies in the eyes of the people.

Comment: I'd give two up votes if I could. Gave me some ideas for my own campaign:)

Comment: As a chatty comment, I will say that a rival adventuring party was one of the best things I've done for a sandbox campaign and I wish I had that idea earlier. You can explore that as a consequence for so many things. "Oh, you chose to help Bob with his side-quest instead of Richard? Kay, Richard is getting help from the other party." - distancing it from a PC RPG "accept all side-quests, complete all side-quests, get all rewards" while still giving the option of many side-quests, as a good example of application.

Comment: I think you mean "rob the party" or "steal *from* the party".  "steal the party" would make "the party" the thing that was stolen, and sounds like an awkward description of kidnapping.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm laughing while singing STEAL YO GIRL, but I've edited. Not being a native english speaker usually creates some awkward grammar mistakes specially on prepositions. Sorry :(

Comment: @NautArch you could award a bounty

Answer (score 4):

### Grant XP based on performance

This is a method that is brought up in the fourth point of an article I read about granting XP (http://theangrygm.com/how-to-xp-good/ Just a warning, he does use strong language, some of it is censored comic style, but just be aware if that may bother you).

This can be used to provide incentive to perform well and not just scrape by. Such as 100% xp if nobody goes down, and a percentage decrease every time somebody goes down. This is an alternative to the debilitating effects method if you want to make it unattractive without penalizing the player characters stat wise over time to the point they might rather their characters have died (an extreme example that probably only happens if this occurs frequently, but still). I feel that a lot of the answers given may be more up your alley, but I thought this was still worth putting out there.

Also:

### Talk to your players

Everybody has said this, but that's because it's really important. Just because you don't like them walking away from the fight like this doesn't mean they will appreciate any change to how this is handled. It's your world, but you all share the game. Also, considering how close it was to a TPK, the fear of that might even be enough of a punishment/deterrent, as had one more member gone down....campaign over. It was **THAT** close. So just make sure this will actually make the game better for everyone before you implement extra penalties.

Comment: For AngryGM links, I strongly recommend the disclaimer for his language. Most people don't actually care, but for those who do, the warning is welcome.